# Time is not returned as dynamic because of static issue

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I need to show the latest timestamp through my service class:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss");
    static Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    static List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(
            Arrays.asList(
                          new User("123","abc","A1234567", "a529794b3ea9c05d8f0b5f354dac25e5", "Role-A","Screen A","Execute",sdf.format(timestamp) )));

    @Override
    public List<User> getAll(int offset, int count) {
        return users;
    }
```

The output looks as follows:

```
[{"hkid":"123","username":"abc","passportNo":"A1234567","tokenId":"a529794b3ea9c05d8f0b5f354dac25e5","role":"Role-A","permission":"Execute","timestamp":"2018.04.02.12.16.19","screen":"Screen A"}]
```

Now the issue is that timestamp is not returned as current one as my timestamp filed is static. What necessary changes do I need to make to always get the current timestamp. I have to work with the static object.

Just to add: In pojo I have taken a timestamp as a string

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String passportNo;
    private String tokenId;
    private String role;
    private String Screen ;
    private String permission;
    private String timestamp ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically update it every time `getAll` is called:

```
@Override
public List<User> getAll(int offset, int count) {
    String ts = sdf.format(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    users.forEach(u -> u.setTimestamp(ts));
    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
Arrays.asList(
                          new User("123","abc","A1234567", "a529794b3ea9c05d8f0b5f354dac25e5", "Role-A","Screen A","Execute",sdf.format(timestamp) )))
```

inside your method. In Spring framework beans are loaded as Singletons, so it's a bad practice to use the class variable. Only use method variables.

Answer (score 0):

Member variables that are declared static are only initialized once during construction.
In your case the `timestamp` and the array of `User` objects both require dynamic creation (or you need to add a setter method for the timestamp to the `User` object and call it during).
So in your `getAll` method you need to create the array of users and along with it the timestamp which is then formatted into the response.

```
@Override
public List<User> getAll(int offset, int count) {
    List<User> response = new ArrayList<User>();
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    response.add(new User("123","abc","A1234567", "a529794b3ea9c05d8f0b5f354dac25e5", "Role-A","Screen A","Execute",sdf.format(ts) ));
    return response;
}
```

Variation with setter:

```
@Override
public List<User> getAll(int offset, int count) {
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for(User user : users)
    {
       user.setTimestamp(sdf.format(ts));
    }
    return users;
}
```

Comment: exception is coming at this line List<User> response = ArrayList<User>();

Comment: Sorry, i forgot a new to create the ArrayList. I updated the post.